# What is the keyboard shortcut for comments in IDLE?

Tags: python, comments, python-idle

What is the shortcut key for using comment line in Python IDLE?

Comment: For commenting a line, bring the cursor to the line that you want to comment and press Alt+4. To uncomment an existing comment, press Alt+3. The comment/uncomment options are available under the Format menu.

Comment: Aren't the shortcuts shown in the menus? Or in the settings (if the keyboard shortcuts can be changed)?

Answer (score 0):

For commenting a line, bring the cursor to the line that you want to comment and press `Alt+4` To uncomment an existing comment, press `Alt+3`

Answer (score 0):

Keysets are selected and customized on the Keys tab of the Settings dialog (Options => Configure IDLE).  On the tab, the settings are called `Comment Region` and `Uncomment Region`.

With the Classic Windows, Classic Unix, Classic Mac, and Classic OSX keysets, Alt-3 adds '##' at the beginning of a line or multiple lines if multiple are selected.  Alt-4 removes '##' if present.  For Modern Unix, Control-d and Control-D do the same.